# Microsoft Graph API Scopes in a Xamarin application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to get the groups I'm a part of within a Xamarin application.

Right now, I'm getting a token with this method :

```
    public async Task SignIn()
    {
        if (App.IdentityClientApp != null)
            this.authenticationResult = await App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(new String[] { Constants.ApplicationID });
    }
```

My app ID comes from the Apps.dev.microsoft.com registration portal.

I then acquire another token silently with this method :

```
    private async Task GetTokenForGroups()
    {
        this.authenticationResult = await App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(new String[] { "User.Read", "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" }, null);
    }
```

If I do this, I am prompted to log in with an admin account.
If I do, the token acquisition will be successful but instead of "remembering" the authorization for other non admin users, I am prompted everytime for an admin grant.

If I make this call with only "User.Read" scope :

```
    public void GetAuthenticatedClient()
    {
        try
        {
            this.graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        await GetTokenForGroups();
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", this.authenticationResult.Token);
                    }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not create a graph client: " + ex.Message + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    public async void GetGroups()
    {
        this.GetAuthenticatedClient();
        var groups = await graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();  
    }
```

I get some groups but they seem to be the Outlook groups, not the security ones.

My Graph permission in apps.dev.microsoft.com are completely empty.

How may I be able to read the directory data ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the admin consent workflow. Simply logging in as an admin does not provide consent to non-admin users. There is a specific workflow for enabling that.

Take a look at an article I wrote called [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/). It should provide you with a starting point for wiring up the consent process.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer.
Is the redirect uri important ? Or is that juste something that is used to give a more friendly navigation after conset ?

Comment: It is required but it can be any page. It does return data back that tells you what tenant received consent which is useful to keep track of which users have received consent.